# create dummy date array and show data from databese table by month and year php

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem when showing in HTML, my date array always duplicate when I insert a new record. I already searching for this problem but I still don't get any answer.

```
$list=array();
$month = @$_POST['month'];
$year = @$_POST['year'];

$show = @$_POST['show'];
for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++) {
    $time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);          
    if (date('m', $time)==$month)       
        $list[]=date('d-M-Y, D', $time);
}

foreach ($list as $day) {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_attendance 
WHERE tb_attendance.employee_number = '$employee_number' GROUP BY badge_number, date_in") 
or die (mysql_error());

    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $day; ?> </td>
        <?php if (date('d/m/Y', strtotime($day)) == $data['date_in']) { ?>              
            <td> <?php echo $data['employee_number']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $data['badge_number']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $data['employee_name']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $data['time_in']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $data['time_out']; ?> </td>
        <?php }  elseif (date('d/m/Y', strtotime($day)) != $data['date_in']) { ?>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
    </tr>
<?php  }}} ?>
```

This below is the layout in HTML:

[image]

[These are the tables (tb_logdata & tb_attendance)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErZPg.png)

Comment: For my opinion, use one row for each login (one column for login and one for logout and use datetime format), do you have a valid and checked data from your DB query then you got what you want for each login ? With this you select where you have bad syntax (DB or PHP). For check online your data use [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and give here url for that example if its correct. Do you really need each day show in first column, easy way is only show dates from DB

Comment: You select all data from DB for each day($list) again and again. Get date from $list->day to your SQL query to select specific date, because you got -> for example 31 times same data for each day, and DB is working a lot in vain. but for me is still much easy way select only dates from DB if its not nessesary full list of date without DB data.

Comment: You should avoid using mysql_* functions. The mysql extension is deprecated and removed from Php 7. It has been replaced with mysql_nd and mysqli extension

Comment: Can you provide the code which is being used to add the records to database ?. You can prevent duplicate records from being added by adding a unique index to a database table field such as employee_number